Edges of VFX are obviously stitched in
I have a project I am working on, mostly just to see how to use VFX. It uses Depth of Field, some bump mapping, and renders using Cycles GPU compute. For the background (still image), I am using the built in FSpy example project (also because I am learning to use FSpy). When I render it, it all looks okay, except for the fact that, along the edges of the render (not the background image), it is obviously stitched in. How can I fix this?

This looks like a problem of straight/premultiplied alpha. I can't guess anything else without more informations. Consider uploading your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/.

I am using compositing. It uses Alpha Over with the render being transparent, if that helps.

Sorry if I wasted anybody's time, but I figured it out. For some odd reason, the sample count was at 1. Crank it up higher, and the weird stitch lines disappear.
